# how to clean local storage on browser close in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

how to clean local storage on browser close in react js

i have try JavaScript events before unload but not found any thing good how to clean local storage on browser close in react js

Comment: If you don't want to persist data when the page closes, then don't write it into local storage to begin with…?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Otherwise, I'd suggest you to just use sessionStorage instead as it is cleared when browser closes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this useEffect in `app.js` file:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cleanupLocalStorage = () => {
        localStorage.clear();
    };
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', cleanupLocalStorage);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', cleanupLocalStorage);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: this code is working but when i reload the page or navigate to any other route then it is also working i dont need that

Comment: If that's the thing then you can store data in session storage

Comment: I have updated my Answer please do try this I used the `beforeunload` event this time

Comment: Shubh Rajawat
not working your soltion